# No existe la interfaz ApplicationContext de spring framework (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Estoy intentado empezar con *Spring* creando un proyecto y estoy intentando instanciar la interfaz `ApplicationContext` de *Spring* y *Eclipse*, no me lo reconoce, es como si no existiera.

Aqui mi **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springapp-1</groupId>
  <artifactId>springapp-1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Creo que los tengo todos, estoy intentado crear esto:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring_config.xml"
        );      
        Administrador administrador = applicationContext
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Dentro de `org.springframework.context` solo aparecen más paquetes, nada más.

Comment: Actualiza las referencias de maven en el proyecto. Selecciona el proyecto, presiona Alt + F5 y acepta. Quizás ese sea el problema.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, gracias por la info, pero no, sigue sin aparecer.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Cerrar el Eclipse.
2. Abrir la consola.
3. Compilar, y ver la salida. Si es con *Maven*, forzar la descarga con `-U`.

Si todo está bien, reabrir el *Eclipse* para ver si ya la reconoce.